# PS module ExchangeOnlineManagement unable to find type

Tags: powershell, exchange

I am trying to connect to Exchangeonline vias powershell and I get below error :

```
Unable to find type [Microsoft.Exchange.Management.RestApiClient.ExchangeEnvironment].
At C:\ProgramFiles\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\exchangeonlinemanagement\netFramework\ExchangeOnlineManagement.psm1:274 char:9
+         [Microsoft.Exchange.Management.RestApiClient.ExchangeEnvironm ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Microsoft.Excha...angeEnvironment:TypeName) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound
```

I just did below commands to install a module :

```
Install-Module -Name ExchangeOnlineManagement

Import-Module -Name ExchangeOnlineManagement
```

Also, I opened the ps1. and try to run ExchangeOnlineManagement.psm1 and got error.

```
Import-Module : The specified module 'Microsoft.Exchange.Management.RestApiClient.dll' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.
```

Any suggestion for troubleshooting?

Comment: What happens if you run `Import-Module ExchangeOnlineManagement -Force` and then `Import-Module ExchangeOnlineManagement`??

Comment: After I ran the first part I got this : Import-Module : Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\ExchangeOnlineManagement\netFramework\Microsoft.Exchange.Management.RestApiClient.dll' or o
ne of its dependencies. Operation is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515)
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\ExchangeOnlineManagement\netFramework\ExchangeOnlineManagement.psm1:4 char:1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the prerequisites for the Exchange Online PowerShell module and compare the detailed steps on Install and maintain the Exchange Online PowerShell module with you did before to check if there is any difference between official blog and your action.

Detailed blog: [Install and maintain the Exchange Online PowerShell module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/exchange-online-powershell-v2?view=exchange-ps#install-and-maintain-the-exchange-online-powershell-module)

If above steps configured correctly, follow the guidance to connect to exchange online: [Connect to Exchange Online PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/connect-to-exchange-online-powershell?view=exchange-ps)